# Accessing config.yml from another file (Bukkit)

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I have created an Economy Plugin for my server, and it works perfectly.
Players can type in /bal and see their balance.
My server also has a GUI Plugin, and one of these options is to see their currency.
I keep player's currencies stored in a config.yml file in my Economy Plugin.
How could I access variables in my Economy config.yml, if I wanted to access them from another plugin? I have scoured the whole internet and have found nothing.
If anyone has any idea on how to do this, please tell me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is several ways to do this but in my opinion best for you is to make Player **class**. It will be storing player data (like currency) and then during development of another plugin import your Economy resource as a dependency.

In Economy Plugin:

> 1. Store player currency in Player object
> 2. Store all Player objects in collection
> 3. Make public function which will be returning player object from your collection, for example as a function parameter pass player nick

In all another plugins:

> 1. Import your Economy plugin as a dependency
> 2. Use your function (for example `getPlayer('YourNick');`)
> 3. If player exists in collection this code will return object of your entity
> 4. Get player currency via getter

Remember to synchronize object data every time you making some changes (for example when player is buying something)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am not really sure how to implement this however. Have you perhaps got Discord so I could speak with you on there?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a configuration file from another plugin.

```
File configFile = new File(<JavaPlugin Object>.getServer().getWorldContainer().getAbsolutePath() + "/plugins/<Your Plugin Name>/config.yml"); // First we will load the file.
FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile); // Now we will load the file into a FileConfiguration.
```

After this we can get values from the config.

```
boolean randomValue = config.getBoolean("randomValue"); // Gets a boolean value.
```

Congratulations! You now can read values from another plugin!